# Does having access to an application that implements encryption and decryption make it easier to crack?

Tags: encryption, hash, aes, sha, cracking

Say I have an application that is to read and write files which are protected with a hash (to detect tampering and corruption) and optionally encryption with a user's key.  The application will necessarily include compiled code to hash, encrypt and decrypt the data.

Assuming we are using rigorous algorithms like salted and stretched AES-256 and SHA-256, is the fact that the user has the application in compiled form (and with some effort could presumably work out the algorithms being used) make it any easier for them to crack the encryption, or generate a fake hash?

If this is in fact a serious vulnerability, what measures would anyone suggest to mitigate the vulnerablity?

Comment: What do you mean "compiled code to hash"?  You don't compile code to a hash, but you can do something like create an md5sum hash from the compiled code.  Is that what you mean?  Oh also what do you mean "the application in compiled form?"  You mean encrypted form?

Comment: EVERY code that runs on the user's device can be reengineered, otherwise the maschine couldn't run that code. You can however make the cracking as hard as possible, but with enough effort everything can be cracked.

Comment: Sorry @Eric, lost in translation.   I meant: "The application will naturally need to include the compiled code necessary to compute the hash of the data, and encrypt and decrypt the data".  And no, I wasn't intending to encrypt the application. By "application in compiled form", I mean the application EXE and DLL files installed on the user's machine.

Comment: The question makes it plenty clear that you don't really understand security or cryptography. You may want to freshen up your knowledge before taking up this task. E.g. you cannot salt or stretch a hash and you should generate a signature or possibly a MAC over the configuration, not a hash.

Comment: @owlstead ummm.....I certainly don't understand everything (hence the OQ).  I didn't intend to imply I was going to salt hashes, maybe I should have used parentheses in the sentence to make the order of evaluation explicit.  I didn't think a MAC was suitable in my application because the receiver of the file needs to be able to detect tampering without the need for the sender to supply them a key.

Comment: OK, so how do you know that the hash has not been tampered with?

Comment: By generating the hash of the data at the receiving end and comparing it with the hash that was supplied with the data - although I think I am seeing a basic flaw with that approach - an adversary could tamper with the data and (with the knowledge of the algorithm used) generate a new hash that matched their tampered version of the data and replace the supplied hash.  So how can I detect tampering without requiring the recipient to know a key?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only case when having an application source would be a vulnerability is when the application itself has a serious flaw, for example

- Is employing a [*security through obscurity*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity) technique,
- Embeds a secret in the body of the program,
- Makes a mistake in implementing a well-known algorithm that opens up the implementation to an attack.

Essentially, your product becomes more vulnerable when an attacker has its source, because the attacker can more easily spot your coding mistakes. However, it's coding mistakes that make your application crackable, not the fact that an attacker has your source code.

Comment: So are you saying that announcing "my application uses XYZ123 to encrypt the data, and the source code I used can be found at..." is not a vulnerability provided the implementation is sound?

Comment: @rossmcm Provided that the implementation that you are using is safe, this may even deter the attackers if the library is known to be good. You have to trust the implementation that you are using anyway, because if the library turns out to be vulnerable at some later time, so would be your application.

Comment: Excellent response. The public scrutiny such an application would then face might highlight and repair any mistakes. So, all in all, it's a great thing to announce this proudly and widely.